# How to get system icons corresponding to specified file type in Windows and paste them into html?

Tags: java

How to get system icons corresponding to specified file type in Windows and paste them into html?

Answer (score 0):

Most icons are stored in `C:\Windows\System32\Shell32.dll`. You'll need some icon editor to get them out.